# How to start up jboss in Windows?

Tags: logging, jboss

I just downloaded jboss folder on my windows. I am having super hard time starting up jboss. I was able to startup jboss without any parameters  and it works fine.

Problem:
The problem is when ever I add port in my parameters than I get an error. I am not sure if I need to change some xml file or something.... I have no idea how to fix this.

I want to start up jboss with following parameters.

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Java\jdk1.7\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Java\jdk1.7\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.access
```

This is the error I get.

```
Calling "C:\jboss-eap-6.1\bin\standalone.conf.bat" 
===============================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-eap-6.1
  JAVA_HOME: C:\Java\jdk1.7
  JAVA: C:\Java\jdk1.7\bin\java


  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_60_X64\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_60_X64\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.access
===============================================================================


Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:191)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:823)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:260)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:456)


WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
Jul 23, 2014 2:18:50 PM org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl <clinit> INFO: JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
Jul 23, 2014 2:18:50 PM org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService start INFO: JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) starting
Jul 23, 2014 2:18:51 PM org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext executeStep



ERROR: JBAS014612: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([])
java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014670: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:99)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:440)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:322)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:229)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:224)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:232)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:333)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:308)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:188)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011592: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:91)
    ... 10 more


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011592: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
         at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingExtension.initialize(LoggingExtension.java:103)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:97)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:127)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:113)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)


Jul 23, 2014 2:18:51 PM org.jboss.as.server.ServerService boot
FATAL: JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

Open command prompt 
Go to JBOSS_HOME\bin
run standalone.bat like this

```
standalone.bat -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
```

OR 
Add below line in standalone.conf.bat

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
```

Now you can just click on standalone.bat

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, do the following:

1. Go to the JBOSS_HOME location on the file system e.g. c:\jboss\appserver\jboss-eap-6.3, look in the bin folder and open the configuration file named, standalone.conf, in a text editor.
2. At the top of the file, add the following line - JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.logmanager".
3. Scroll-down the file, to where JVM options are specified and add the following two options:

   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final-redhat-1.jar"

Note: You may need to modify the exact path to the logmanager jar file, as the one on your jboss installation may differ from what applies here. The JBoss EAP version being used in this case was 6.3.0GA. A different version may have a different path to the logmanager jar file.

4. Simply save the modified 'standalone.conf' file, with these couple of changes, and re-attempt starting up of the JBoss App server (either on the CLI or within Eclipse).

Note: For fixing the issue for a JBoss EAP appserver instance running just within Eclipse, simply open the server's launch configuration and add the 2 JVM options to the VM arguments of the launch configuration, as shown in the screenshot below:

5. Voila! The startup issue with regards to failure to load the LogManager, is resolved.

Check this blogpost for details and screenshots - http://obinnakalu.blogspot.com/2014/10/jboss-enterprise-application-platform.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-logmodule org.jboss.logmanager` argument when executing `standalone.bat`. According to this [post](https://community.jboss.org/message/715578) this resolved the problem.

Comment: thanks, petr. just one last thing. how can I add argument when executing standalone.bat? I am just clicking standalone.bat file.

Comment: Open `Start` type `cmd`, press enter. `cd` to directory where $JBOSS_HOME/bin` is and type `standalonet.bat -logmodule org.jboss.logmanager -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager` - you can also add your other options, I omitted them for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs when I try to start an embedded WildFly AS server by run maven test.
From the stack trace, we can see we need to add "java.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager" as a system property, but how and where? I have tried many kinds of way but all failed.
Finally, I found it's the pom.xml file works as following:

```
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
         </configuration>
  ...
```

Hope this can help you also.